# 'Failed to access device' when trying to root Samsung Galaxy S 2.3.3 with Heimdall

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s, heimdall

I want to install CyanogenMod on my Samsung Galaxy S. In order to do that it needs to be rooted first of course. For that I followed the the [explanation on the CyanogenMod wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S%3a_Full_Update_Guide) to the letter.

However, when I execute `heimdall flash --kernel zImage` in the command prompt I get the following feedback:

```
D:\SGS\Heimdall>heimdall flash --kernel zImage
Heimdall v1.3.1, Copyright (c) 2010-2011, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
ERROR: Failed to access device. libusb error: -12
```

I'm unable to find any information about this error :-(.

Type: Samsung Galaxy GT-I9000
Firmware: 2.3.3
Baseband: I9000XXJVO
Kernel: 2.6.35.7-I9000XWJVH-CL184813
OS: Windows Vista

Alternatively: where can I find a clear, non-confusing, guide on how to root a Samsung Galaxy S? There seem to be hundreds out there but so far I didn't find any that worked for me with working links and clear explanation.

Comment: Did you reboot into the bootloader (Download Mode)?

Comment: Problem solved in the mean time but yes I had, tx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following page for downloading the required files:
http://www.theandroidsoul.com/how-to-root-xwjvh-android-2-3-3-rom-for-galaxy-s-i9000/

1. Install Samsung Kies but dont keep it running while flashing as it will interfere with the process. Required only for the drivers.
2. Download CF-Root kernel. File name – CF-Root-XW_NEE_JVH-v3.2-CWM3RFS.zip.
   Unzip the above file. You will get the .tar file – “CF-Root-XW_NEE_JVH-v3.2-CWM3RFS.tar”.
3. Download Odin. File name – Odin3 v1.7. Extract the zip file to get Odin3 1.7.exe. Run Odin by double clicking on it.
4. Switch Off your phone. Wait for vibration to confirm complete switch off.
   Boot your phone in Download Mode — Press and hold “VolumeDOWN + HOME key + POWER button” together.
5. Connect your phone to PC now. You’ll notice “Added! !” message in the message box.
   On Odin, click the “PDA” box and select the .tar file you got in step 2 — CF-Root-XW_NEE_JVH-v3.2-CWM3RFS.tar
6. Do NOT select any “.pit” file in the “PIT” box, and make sure “Repartition” button is NOT checked.
   Leave the “Auto Reboot” and “F. Reset Time” buttons checked.
   Click the Start button on Odin to begin installing the CF Root kernel.
   After the CF Root is installed, phone will restart.
   Your phone is rooted now. Note that surperuser app is there.

Comment: Phone rooted in about 3 minutes with the clear guide! Tx a bunch!

Comment: Answers that are just links to outside resources are not considered good answers. When that link ceases to function this answer will have no value whatsoever. Please at least summarize what someone will find when they follow that link.

Comment: @AlEverett:The answer would be too long if I post the entire page here.

Comment: Which is why I said "summarize".

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who wants to know. I had the same problem.
**My Solution**: Was to use another computer; worked for me!!